# Отсутствие текста в AlertDialog'е

Tags: android, kotlin, text, dialog

AlertDialog создается без текста. Kotlin. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val drawerResult: Drawer.Result? = null
lateinit var fragment: Fragment

lateinit var dialog: DialogFragment

var fm = fragmentManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    Drawer()
            .withActivity(this)
            //.withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.stock).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_dropbox),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.projects).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_picture_o),
                    DividerDrawerItem(),
                    SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog),
                    SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.about).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id, drawerItem ->
                // Обработка клика
                //get title clicked item
                //MainActivity.this.getString(((Nameable) drawerItem).getNameRes())
                //val fm = fragmentManager

                when (position) {
                    1 -> fragment = Stock()
                    2 -> fragment = Projects()
                    4 -> fragment = Settings()
                    5 -> fragment = About()
                }

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, position.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit()
            }
            .build()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, i ->
                dialog.cancel()
                finish()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, i ->
            }
            .create().show()
}
```

}

Comment: Секцию imports еще укажите в исходном коде.

Answer (score 1):

А чем билдер-то не угодил? Он все умеет как надо сделать.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme)
            .setTitle(R.string.exit_application)
            .setMessage(R.string.exit_application_message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
                finish()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            .create().show()
}
```

Comment: Все равно текста нет